# Unable to install Tensorflow using pip in Python 3.8.3

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

This is my cmd with the error.

[image: Error from cmd]

> C:\Users>pip install tensorflow
>
> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
> tensorflow (from versions: none)
>
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow

what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a 32-bit build of Python. Three is no 32-bit build of tensorflow, so it is not available. Install the 64 bit build of Python and use that. Then tensorflow will install.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
python -m pip install tensorflow
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly, install the x64 version of Python from https://www.python.org/downloads/ followed by upgrading your pip version.
2. You can issue the command: `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` to upgrade your pip version (If not already in the latest version). At the time of writing this comment, the latest version of pip is 21.2.4.
3. Next install TensorFlow by issuing the command: `python -m pip install tensorflow`.
4. If the error still persists, then uninstall TensorFlow using command: `python -m pip uninstall tensorflow`.
5. Clear the temp files on the PC. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and type "temp", delete all the files. Then Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and type "%temp%", deleting all the files.
6. Finally restart your PC/Laptop.
7. Install Tensorflow using the command: `python -m pip install tensorflow`.

Now, Tensorflow should be installed successfully.